# how to reverse trackpoint direction?

Tags: xorg, 17.10, lenovo, scrolling, trackpoint

I would like to ask the following question. I installed Ubuntu 17.10.1 on my Thinkpad X1C 5th gen. Trackpoint worked after putting the kernel option "psmouse.proto=bare". But, I can not change the scrolling direction. Now, pushing the trackpoint up (toward the display) scrolls a window down and pushing the trackpoint down (toward the trackpad) scrollls a window up. How can I reverse this scrolling?

I created the file 
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-evdev.conf 
with the following content:

---

Section "InputClass"
 Identifier "Touchpad/TrackPoint"
 MatchProduct "PS/2 Generic Mouse"
 MatchDriver "evdev"
 Option "EmulateWheel" "1"
 Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
 Option "Emulate3Buttons" "0"
 Option "XAxisMapping" "7 6"
 Option "YAcisMapping" "5 4"
EndSection

---

Then, I changed the XAxisMapping into "6 7". But, even after logout/login, nothing has changed on the scrolling. What should I do instead? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I switched to Cinnamon and it solved. But, still solutions for original gnome setting is welcome!

Comment: Please, show the output of `xinput list-props Trackpoint` *(with the Trackpoint replaced with either its name or its id from the `xinput list` output)*.

Comment: Oops, I did not notice your comment!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you've got a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem on my Thinkpad T420s running Arch, but it should work on Ubuntu just the same.

## Step 1

**Get the name of the Trackpoint:**

```bsh
$ xinput list
```

The name of the Trackpoint is referred to as `<device>`, if it contains spaces, the name must be put into quotes. On my T420s the Trackpoint is called `"TPP/2 IBM TrackPoint"`.

## Step 2

**Get the name of the option for natural scrolling:**

```bsh
$ xinput list-props <device>
```

The name of the option is referred to as `<option>`, again it must be put into quotes, if it contains spaces. For my Trackpoint the option is called `"libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled"`.

## Step 3

**Set the option to the desired setting:**

```bsh
$ xinput set-prop <device> <option> <setting>
```

For natural scrolling, the `<setting>` is `1`, so the entire command is:

```bsh
$ xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

## Step 4

**Make the setting permanent with the `.xprofile` file:**

```bsh
$ echo 'xinput set-prop <device> <option> <setting>' >> ~/.xprofile
```

The `.xprofile` file is sourced on startup of `Xorg`.
That means, the command is executed every time the PC starts the display server for graphics.
If you don't use a display manager put it in `.xinitrc`.

Comment: Thank you! Now, it works like a charm.

Comment: This seems Xorg specific, does anyone know how this would look in wayland?