# Enable Natural Scrolling for Trackpoint on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, configuration, scrolling, trackpoint

How to enable natural scrolling for a trackpoint on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?
There are many questions and answers to this, for instance [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000016/how-to-reverse-trackpoint-direction/1199992#1199992), [2](https://era86.github.io/2018/06/13/natural-trackpoint-scrolling-on-thinkpad-in-ubuntu-1604.html), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067196/natural-scrolling-in-18-04-system-wide).
They are outdated and do not work for me. For instance, [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000016/how-to-reverse-trackpoint-direction/1199992#1199992) suggests to do

```
$ xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

However, I do not have such the device `TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint` nor anything similar.
The command `xinput list` outputs:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:16                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:16                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:16                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:16                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to set this property for device with ID=6, but it errored `property 'libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`.

I also tried to modify `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` and update the lines as documented in [4](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Libinput):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "True" # does not work
EndSection
```

and then restart, but to no avail. (replacing "True" to "true", "1", 1 did not help).

Suggestions?

Additional info: the laptop is ThinkPad Yoga X1 Gen7, the output of `sudo libinput list-devices` contains the block:

```
Device:           TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```